# Is there any way to only build frontend of Tauri, but without backend?

Tags: tauri

I build a tauri app, but I have only used typescript to implement it,
have not used the rust backend but the application still built a rust server, I think it will expense cpu and memory cost，is there any way to only build frontend of tauri, but without backend ?

Comment: Without the "backend" there is no tauri "app", only your frontend. If you want to build only your frontend then you can just do `npm run build` (or whatever is listed in beforeBuildCommand in tauri.conf.json) and take the files out of the dist dir. Those files however are a typical non-tauri frontend which means they have to be opened in the normal browser, need some kind of server to serve them, and you of course have no access to Tauri specific apis.

Answer (score 1):

To build only the **frontend** part you'd want to run `npm run dev` and it will execute the underline command to run your **frontend** which most likely will call `vite` command.

Thought it won't compile the binary application itself, since it depends on getting the rust **backend** compiled.

If you want to run just the frontend part with minimal backend, after the first rust compilation everything is cached, and it is still smaller than Electron and other similar solutions.